# RailsAdmin not figuring out composite key

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-admin

I have a table in postgres with a composite key. I am trying to access it using rails_admin.

Model.rb:

```
 class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'schema.tablename'
  establish_connection :db
end
```

I can see the count of rows and the table name and everything. But when I click on the table in the admin UI, it fails with this error

`: SELECT  "schema"."tablename".* FROM "schema"."tablename" ORDER BY schema.tablename. desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

The id is missing in the order by clause. Is this because it is a composite id? How do I get rails admin to properly identify the id of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a problem with `rails_admin` but with ActiveRecord. ActiveRecord does not support composite keys. I had to install a gem called `composite_primary_keys` and then define the composite key in the model. Rails Admin was then able to pick up the correct id and display the entries.